# vue/no-unused-vars with Vue Js Dynamic Slot Names

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eslint

I am using vuejs and vue-bootstrap and have this slot within b-table so I can apply a filter to only a couple fields within my table:

```
  <template
    v-for="item in items"
    v-slot:[`cell(${item})`]="data"
  >
    {{ data.value | filter }}
  </template>
```

`items` is an object in my data.

All works but I'm now getting a lint error `'item' is defined but never used vue/no-unused-vars.`. It's obvious why I am getting it but is there a way to make it understand I'm using the variable or a better way to achieve the above?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the unused vars warnings in the `eslintConfig` part of your `package.json` file:

```
"rules": {
      "no-unused-vars": "off"
}
```